# Логика: троичная, тернарная, трехзначная?

Tags: заимствования

Всем привет с ХэшКода.

Возник вопрос, как правильно перевести "**ternary logic**".

Варианты:

- **Троичная**. Вариант адекватный, но: троичная система счисления работает на операндах `0, 1, 2`, а логика - `-1, 0, 1`. У двоичной("binary") логики такого противоречия нет.
- **Трехзначная**. Этот вариант есть в словарях, но мне непонятен (потому что, например, "123" - трехзначное число).
- **Тернарная**. Слово такое есть, транскрипция с английского, все хорошо, но: именно слово "тернарный" означает несколько другое, "трехсоставный" (сплав, например, "ternary alloy"), "трехаргументный"(функция `f(x, y, z)`).

Что выбрать?

*P.S.: Все три варианта есть в разных словарях. Адекватно по смыслу будет название "трехсимвольная" или "логика трех состояний", но они совсем дикие и громоздкие.*

**UPDATE**: Словари подсказали, что "троичный" и "тернарный" имеют одно общее значение (состоящий из трех частей), просто используются в разных сферах, как вышеупомянутые сплав и логика. Собственно, и различия пришли из сфер, и сам я зачем-то повелся на "систему счисления". Т.к. слово "троичный" — русское, видимо, остановлюсь на нем. Если я нигде не ошибся, вопрос можно закрывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sh4dow, все три варианта, найденные вами в словарях, будут верными. Причина проста: они все уже фактически используются в русскоязычной (как оригинальной, так и переводной) литературе. Конечно, терминологическая синонимия не есть хорошо, однако в компьютерных и информационных науках она встречается сплошь и рядом. В этой связи уместно вспомнить, что и оригинальный термин употребляется наряду с синонимами: logic в англоязычной литературе не только ternary, но и three-valued (этот вариант используется вроде бы чаще), trivalent, trinary. Мой языковой вкус считает наиболее удачным вариант *троичная*. Ваше опасение по поводу его противоречивости, как мне кажется, беспочвенно. Если я верно понимаю, то суть этой логики в использовании **трёх** логических значений. А уж **какими** они будут (false|unknown|true; -1|0|+1; 0|1|2; black|grey|white и т.д.) – вторично. Можно рассуждать и дальше о достоинствах и недостатках остальных вариантов, но, думаю, суть ясна: выбор всецело за автором текста – то есть, вероятно, за вами.
Хэшкоду взаимный привет!
**Update:** едва успел добавить ответ, как увидел ваш апдейт. Разными путями мы с вами пришли к единому ответу. :)

Comment: Вот я к похожему выводу пришел) Спасибо за уточнение :)